# Responsive layout is not exactly in the position I want

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have been trying to leave a responsive layout a week ago that is very similar to a website I found, but I can not do it at all. I am sending the images of the responsive site that I saw and I am sending the image of how is mine.

The site I want to do similar is this:

http://mapa.buenosaires.gob.ar

And the site I want to do the same is in git, you can make the clone, download, share, whatever you want:

https://github.com/eltonsantos/snippets_uteis/tree/master/sidebar_bootstrap

The normal part of the site, full screen and big I was able to do exactly as I want, but the responsive part I'm not getting, everything is broken, distorted and in the wrong place. Please, can anyone help me?

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Even though I use the media queries I can not exactly leave it as it is on the site and I would at least understand why. Can someone help me?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS reads from top to bottom, what that means is that changes that has been done to an element on the mobile version, may get a new style if the desktop css property is read after. So what you will hade to do is to reset css code.

For an example,

```
// This is mobile CSS
.btn {
    color: red;
} 

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    // this is desktop CSS
    .btn {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

If we we're to leave the desktop CSS btn without color, it would automatically have the color red. But now we override it.